# Homebrew: tap creation, move package files during installation

Tags: installation, package, homebrew

I'm trying to figure out how (and if it's possible) to tell brew that when person x installs my package it has to put some files in a folder and some in others.
For example you usually use /etc/ folder for config files: let's say i have project "project" like

> - file1.py
> - file2.js
> - file3.blablabla
> - configfile.conf

and i want that when someone launches `brew install project` file 1, 2 and 3 get put inside default brew folder while configfile.conf gets moved in /etc/project/. I have seen many packages moving files around during installation, but brew's docs don't cover this case and looking it up on google results only in people asking how to move homebrew installation folder.

Is this possible or do i have to organize the whole project inside the same folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer, it was not well explained in the docs, but was there:
[Here are the docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook)

The answer is under "just moving some files" section:
Inside your .rb script, you have the def install function. If you look at the docs there is a table containing lots of directories

```
prefix      #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/Cellar/#{name}/#{version}    /usr/local/Cellar/foo/0.1
opt_prefix  #{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/opt/#{name}             /usr/local/opt/foo
bin         #{prefix}/bin                  /usr/local/Cellar/foo/0.1/bin
etc...
```

These are the directories where you can install files.
For example i had to move my script inside `bin` folder and a config file inside `etc` folder, so i wrote

```
def install
    etc.install "config"  # move file "config" to etc directory
    bin.install "script"  # move file "script" to bin directory
end
```

N.B.: etc and bin are not `/etc/` and `/bin/` but those specified inside brew's docs. In this case `#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc` and `#{prefix}/bin` where HOMEBREW_PREFIX is `/usr/local` and prefix is brew's installation folder.